# Platform Pause / Resume events not firing in Capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I was trying to use these events for my autologout timer functionality however I now realise that these events are not available yet in Capacitor.
https://forum.getcapacitor.com/t/platform-pause-platform-resume-not-working/249

**Does anyone know a workaround of accessing these events or similar without using native plugins?**

I can't use plugins as the webview of the device is fixed to an old version (44).

Edit:
It turns out I can use some native plugins just not the Capacitor ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These Cordova events have now been added to Capacitor Beta 22 for backward compatibility and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cordova events [description](https://github.com/apache/cordova-docs/blob/master/www/docs/en/dev/cordova/events/events.md)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.